# Is it possible to use static electricity to grab paper and then release paper by discharging?

Tags: electromagnetism

I need to build a device that can transport bits of paper one sheet at a time. I was thinking of using electrostatic force to attach paper to the rod, stick or whatever. The rod will then move the piece of paper to a different positon where it will place it precisely at the correct coordinates and then release.

I know of course it is possible to use static electricity to attach paper to things, however I don't know if discharging will release the paper? Probably a stupid question, but I've never really seen it done before.

Comment: How do you intend to discharge it? And what of e.g. polyester sheets, that can hold charge for a decent amount of time?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - I'm not really sure. I had the idea yesterday, and so far I thought of using some sort of metal contact for the paper, since it would be simple to discharge, I assume. My physics is quite rusty, so can't remember much about electrostatics. How would one discharge polyester?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: I think you'd do much better to use vacuum instead of static charge to hold the paper. Easily controllable; no shock hazards; extremely common technology for moving objects around on production lines.

Comment: @LeonHeller: This question is on-topic because it relates to "the theory and simulation of electromagnetic forces" (http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Not every question has to be about designing a circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discharging the item will definitely release the paper.

However, I would recommend against using static electricity in this case. You can make it work, but the whole thing will be very humidity-sensitive -- for example, if the paper is slightly moist, it might conduct enough electricity to charge whatever is underneath it.